# What makes the gcc compiler when i have the same header file in different paths

Tags: c, gcc

I have an issue, i try to find out what is going on in a worst use case.
I have two different headers with the same name.

worstcase.h in /path/to/case

```
#ifndef WORSTCASE_H
#define WORSTCASE_H

#define CASE 20;

#endif
```

and the same header in /path/to/case_2nd

```
#ifndef WORSTCASE_H
#define WORSTCASE_H

#define CASE 40;

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "worstcase.h"

int main() {
int i = CASE
}
```

I would like to compile it with the command `gcc -o main main.c -I /path/to/case -I /path/to/case_2nd`

And now i want to know if the compiler shows an error, a warning, nothing or i have to change some options for more safety ?

If i try at my Fedora, i don't have a warning or something else.

Comment: that is the point of the ifndef, the first one should take the second one skipped, add a printf to your example and print out the case to see which worked, reverse the -I paths on the command line and try again ,see if it changes

Comment: @dwelch ok, it's not important your scope, but i try to imagine in a huge project, which a lot of people working together, what will be the effect of a mistake from only one person.

Comment: the mistake is they wipe out the define, and/or create a compiler or linker error

Comment: if you design a solution like this then everyone has to play by the rules otherwise the solution fails. and you cannot predict ahead of time all the possible failures

Comment: Wouldn't it just include the first "worstcase.h" it finds as it goes through (the current directory followed by) the include paths you gave it?  Why would there be a warning or error?

Comment: @BlueMoon if u dont like mistake then i call it Sabotage...

Answer (score 0):

C permits compilers to do more or less anything to locate the file to include for an `#include` directive in which the file name is enclosed in quotation marks, as your is.  In any case, however, it will choose exactly one file to include for each such directive encountered (or fail if it cannot find any).

As most compilers do, GCC in particular maintains a path in which it searches for include files.  This is influenced by the `-I` options in your compilation command.  For headers specified in quotes, the directory of the current file is always first in that path.  When it encounters an `#include` directive, GCC checks each directory in the search path until it finds one that contains a file of the specified name.  That file is the one included.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to use `#include ./path/to/include/header.h` directive but is seems to be the only robust solution.

Comment: If by "robust" you mean something along the lines of "portable", then you should think again.  At minimum, you cannot be sure how the `.` path segment will be interpreted.  Probably you should use something more like `#include "module/header.h"`.  The `module/` part distinguishes which of the like-named headers you mean, and you will plan on doing whatever you need to do for your compiler to be able to find the header (i.e. put the parent directory of `module/` in the header search path).